# Ttitlesec package and underlining subsubsections

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I am desperately trying to underline the headings of the `subsubsection` title.

Here is my problem. If I use this piece of code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\subsubsectionfont{\underline}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{subsubsection example}

\end{document}
```

I get this result(no underline):

[image]

If I use this piece of code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}
%\usepackage{titlesec}

\subsubsectionfont{\underline}
%\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{subsubsection example}

\end{document}
```

I get this (underlined but no `titlesec` package):

[image]

And if I use this piece of code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%\subsubsectionfont{\underline}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\underline}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{subsubsection example}

\end{document}
```

I get this error:

`Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode`.

So my problem is that I can't use `titlesec` and underline a `subsubsection` at the same time.

Is there any way that I can fix that ?

Thank you in advance for any response

Comment: Would `\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{\underline}` solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use underline. This  dates back to the times of typewriters, when it was the only simple way to emphasize text.

However, if you insist, here's a way to obtain what you want: use the advanced interface of `titlesec` and the `soulutf8` package (I suppose you use `utf8` input encoding). The code differs slightly, depending on whether you want to underline only subsubsection title or title + label. For the latter uncomment the two commented lines,  and comment the two previous lines. You can choose the underline depth, thickness and color. It allows hyphenation, in case of multilined titles.

Just a final comment: don't load both `titlesec` and `sectsty`,, they interfere.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\setulcolor{IndianRed3}\setul{1ex}{1.2pt}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont}{\color{IndianRed3}\bfseries\thesubsubsection}{0.5em}{\ul}

%\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
%\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont}{}{0em}{\ul{\thesubsubsection\enspace#1}}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection example}

\end{document}
```

[image]