# LaTeX error: Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode

Tags: packages, titlesec

I have an annoying error that is appearing at line 7.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\sffamily\large\bfseries\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-4pt}{1pt}}    

\begin{document}
\section*{Trig Identities}
\end{document}
```

The rending of the text is happening just fine. It is just more of an annoyance.

Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode

[image]

I tried looking at other people that have had this same error, but I am new to LaTeX and I couldn't understand the solutions.

Comment: I suspect it's some sectsty package's incompatibilities...

Comment: See, it's mentioned in [sectioning - Ttitlesec package and underlining subsubsections - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308369/ttitlesec-package-and-underlining-subsubsections) that you should not use both.

Comment: (use the approach in the answer there and see if it works.)

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. I just used

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}}
```

I removed the `titlesec` package. Looks very nice now.